# How to create a button component on vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I need to create a component button by clicking on which I will be taken to a third-party site. That is, the button must be created with a dynamic link. I am using vue.storefront. I need to pass store.id and product.id with this link. The link should look like

```
https://base-url/store.id/product.id
```

I created a button component

```
 <template>
  <button><a :href="url">aaaaaa</a></button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'mename',
  data () {
    return {
      url: 'http://myurl'
    }
  },
  methods: {}
}
</script>
```

Please help me solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some code of what you have tried so far. See how to create a [example]

Answer (score 2):

```js
Vue.component('myButton', {
  template: '<button><a :href="url">Go</a></button>',
  data() {
    return {
      url: 'www.google.com'
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-button />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Vue.component('my-button', {
  template: `
    <form :action="this.link">
        <input type="submit" value="Go to Google" />
    </form>
  `,
 props: {
    link: '',
  }
});
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    link: 'google.com'
  },
});
```

Html

```
<div id="app">
<my-button :link="link" />
</div>
```